# Is there a way to stop a DBT model from running if dependency is not resolved?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

I have a scenario where a model **A.sql** selects data from a snapshot B. I need to make sure that the model A doesn't run as long as the snapshot is not created. Is there anyway I can do this?

PS -- DBT is integrated with Google-BigQuery in this scenario. The snapshot and the related datasets will be created in bigquery upon running.

Here is the error message I am getting while running the dbt model A.
[image]

Comment: If `model A` depends on `snapshot B`, I believe the former will never be built unless the latter is already built. dbt should never run a model before all of its upstream dependencies are already built

Comment: Are you using the `ref()` macro in `model A` to reference `snapshot B` in there?

Comment: @AleixCC , I dont want to build model A unless the snapshot B is created. But this is giving me runtime error. How do I handle that error without failing the process?

And yes, I am using ref() in model A to reference snapshot B

Comment: If you are getting an error, then you should share it in the post to make it easier for us to understand your issue and debug.

Comment: Added the error message in the description

Comment: Looks like dbt is failing to find the dataset where your snapshot is. Can you try building the snapshot (`model B`) separately, and check in which dataset it is building?

Comment: Yes that will work. I have a scenario where I need to run the same build in multiple environments. In some of the environments, the snapshot will not be present. For those, I am trying to see if I can work with a single code. For eg, the code(macro) could check if the snapshot is present or not. If it is present, go ahead and run the model, else discard this model.

Comment: seems like you already have a solution in mind. What's blocking you then?

Comment: Sounds like you will want to use jinja to dynamically modify your query.  something like https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/writing-packages-when-a-source-table-may-or-may-not-exist/1487 should get you going.  however, i would really think about this, as it could get unwieldy as time goes on and more development is done.  might be better to abstract this logic to a separate model.

Comment: @rtenha, your suggestion worked. Thank you.